# IMPORTHTML on Google Sheets returning a #N/A error, but only in one document

Tags: google-sheets, import

I have a Google Sheets document where I track the prices of several stocks. I made this a couple of months ago, and have been experiencing this issue for the past couple of weeks:

This formula returns "#N/A", the error description is: "Could not fetch url: https://finviz..."

```
=substitute(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=VOO","table",11),8,2),"*","")
```

However, if I create a new Google Sheets document and use this exact formula, it works. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post a copy of the problematic sheet? without sensitive data please, and editable.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz That is interesting... It had worked fine with 11 for a while, then about a month ago it stopped working but did work with 9. After about a week, it stopped working with 9 and I had to switch back to 11. Then it started again but works for 9 for only some of them. I wonder what it could be about the site that keeps swapping the table number.

Comment: @Aerials Sure, here's a link. Note: I changed the table from 11 to 9 per the above comment. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mscEG2PSuKXVA-KyU4Z6yzS0zR9OHA1nR-vk9nzP2Og/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. Something must have been changed at finviz / google :(
There are also some discussions in the google support groups.
One possible solution could be to put all the symbols you're interested in into one URL, e.g. https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=161&t=FB,AAPL,GOOG,TSLA&ta=0&p=w
and then parse the resulting table.
Unfortunately I am not very good at the parsing part and have to do it by try and error.
But for example

```
=importxml("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=161&t=FB,AAPL,GOOG,TSLA&ta=0&p=w";"//*[@id='screener-content']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table")
```

is at least showing some results in google docs. So this might be something to work with.

Comment: It seems to work again (in most cases) if your replace the table from 11 -> 9: =substitute(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=VOO","table",9),8,2),"*","")

Answer (score -1):

It will work again by removing 'SUBSTITUTE' and switching to table 8.
A2 = stock ticker

=ÍNDICE(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&A2;"table";8);7;2)